# facing an issue while reading json Line 52: 'myJson' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

import React, { Component } from 'react' import { JsonToTable } from "react-json-to-table"; class PostList extends Component {   state = {     todos: []   }   componentDidMount() {     fetch("https://test.***.com/server")   .then(res => res.json())   .then(res => {     this.setState({       todos: res.body.items     });     console.log(this.state.todos);   })   .catch(console.log);   }        myJson = {       Analyst: { name: "Jack", email: "jack@xyz.com" },       "Loaded by": "Jills",       "Load id": 34,       "git id": "xxqaygqertqsg98qhpughqer",       "Analysis Id": "7asdlnagsd98gfaqsgf",       "Load Date": "July 12, 2018",       "Data Source": "Study XY123-456",       "Jira Ticket": "Foo-1",       "Confluence URL": "http://myserver/wxyz",       URI: "https://www.google.com/",       "Study sponsors": [         { name: "john", email: "john@@xyz.com" },         { name: "jane", email: "jane@@xyz.com" }       ]     };     render() {      return (

## Hello There

{   this.state.todos.map((postDetail, index) => {    return

## {postDetail.name}

})      }

## Hello CodeSandbox

### Start editing to see some magic happen!

)   } }  export default PostList

Comment: use `this.state.todos.body` instead `this.PostData.body`

Comment: facing same issue

render() {

    return (
      <div >
        <h1>Hello There</h1>
        {this.state.todos.body((postDetail, index)=>{
          return <h1>{postDetail.name}</h1>


        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Comment: use `map`  like `this.state.todos.body.map((postDetail,index)=>....`

Comment: i have updated the code with map. got below issue

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: do like this `{this.state.todos.body.items.map((postDetail, index) => {
        return <h1>{postDetail.name}</h1>
      })}`

Comment: can u make the changes and provide me the code... my gitlab:  https://github.com/siddartha1729/reactjs.git

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-sea-n7oi4 please check its working.You must validate the array exist before map initialise like this `state.val && state.val.map` its called [condition rendering in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).your server url not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with following minor changes should work.

```
fetch("https://test.XXX.pcf.dell.com/server")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      todos: res.body.items
    });
    console.log(this.state.todos);
  })
  .catch(console.log);
```

and

```
{
  this.state.todos.map((postDetail, index) => {
    return <h1>{postDetail.name}</h1>;
  });
}
```